# How to close a table row evey four items?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I have a Handlebars template where I want to render an array of movies in a table with four columns.

Right now I registered a HBS helper (maybe I'm not doing it correctly):

```
app.engine('handlebars',exphbs({
    defaultLayout: 'main',
    helpers: {
        nextRow: function(index_count, block){
            if(parseInt(index_count)%3 === 0){
                return block.fn(this);
            }
        }
    }
}));

app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
```

And this is my `main` layout:

```
<div>
        <table>
            <tr>
        {{#each movies}}
            <td>
            {{#if this.found}}
                <p><img src="{{this.poster}}" /></p>
                <p><a href='https://netflix.com/title/{{this.show_id}}'>{{this.show_title}}</a></p>
            {{else}}
                <p>{{this.show_title}} {{this.errmsg}}</p>
            {{/if}}
            </td>
            {{#nextRow @index}}
                </tr><tr>
            {{nextRow}}

        {{/each}}
            </tr>
        </table>
</div>
```

But when I run my code like this I get an undefined `html`

Comment: What exactly is the error you are getting?

Comment: Hm, shouldn't that be `{{/nextRow}}`?

Comment: That was it! Silly me

Comment: It isn't tabular data. You shouldn't be using a table. Consider grids instead.

Comment: I'm sorry, I have never heard of Grids before and I can't find any decent explanation on Google. Can you point me to an explanation of grids please?

Answer (score 0):

In the end the problem was that I didn't correctly closed my block on `main.handlebars`

I had `{{nextRow}}` instead of `{{/nextRow}}`